# Rounding when using Math.(sin)

Tags: javascript

```
var PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
var intelect = 33;
var ageInDays = 54

document.write("answer: " + Math.sin(ageInDays*2*PI/intelect));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aRzRc/

Is it possible to round when using `Math.sin`?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [`toFixed`](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/4Tv6H/)?

Comment: By the way, why not using `Math.PI`?

Comment: Shadow Wizard; for this example I was told to use Math.(sin) then round.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed):

```
Math.sin(ageInDays*2*PI/intelect).toFixed(2)); //Ans: 0.76
```

Comment: Even if he's not, it's taught me something new today!

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can;

```
var calc = Math.sin(ageInDays*2*Math.PI/intellect);    
document.write(Math.round(calc));
```

Or, alternatively:

```
document.write("answer: " + Math.round(Math.sin(ageInDays*2*PI/intellect)));
```

There is no need to define your own PI, javascript's math object has a property for that.

Answer (score 0):

What hinders you to use `Math.round` (or `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil`)?

```
var PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
var intelect = 33;
var ageInDays = 54

document.write("answer: " + Math.floor(Math.sin(ageInDays*2*PI/intelect)));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aRzRc/1/

Comment: for this example I was told that I need to use math.sin